# How to use c++ dll into xamarin android?

Tags: c++, dll, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use custom .dll (c++) into xamarin android, however I have tried with p/invoke (Dllimport) but I am getting "DllNotFoundException".
Q> Can we use .dll file into xamarin android project as it is and if yes then how to add it to the project.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I am having same issue.